# Ayuda sql usando dos tablas diferentes

Tags: sql

necesito ayuda para hacer consultas vía `SQL`; tengo dos tablas, una de productos y la otra salida de productos, aquí el código

```
 Select 
        saiprod_codproduto,
        saiprod_quantidade,
        saiprod_valorproduto,
        saiprod_valortotal
  from  saida_produto where  
        saiprod_cod_saida_pai = 1 \\aqui viene una variable este valor para prueba
      group by
        saiprod_codproduto,
        saiprod_quantidade,
        saiprod_valorproduto,
        saiprod_valortotal
```

Resultado, dos registros equivalentes a numero de nota 1

Resultado

```
(1, 1, 7000, 5200);
(2, 1, 5200, 5200);
```

Tenemos el código 1 y 2, ahora lo que necesito es el nombre del producto, que se encuentra en otra tabla

Comment: ¿Cuál es la otra tabla y por qué columna se relaciona con la tabla `saida_produto`?

Comment: Debes hacer uso de los JOINS. Entonces tu consulta al final tendría algo como: JOIN tabla_donde_esta_el_nombre ON (condicion_de_los_campos_que_relacionana_las_tablas) Te dejo algunos ejemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Esta es la tabla ESTOQUE FIELD EST_CODIGO, EST_PRODUTO, EST_UNIDADE, EST_TIPO, EST_PRECOCUSTO, EST_PERCLUCRO, EST_PRECOVENDA, EST_ULTFORNECEDOR, EST_ULTCOMPRADOR, EST_SITUACAO, EST_OBS, EST_FOTO, EST_DATACAD, EST_DATAULTCOMPRA, EST_DATAULTVENDA, EST_QUANTIDADE

Comment: Por favor **[edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/98446/edit)** indicando cómo se llama la otra tabla, por qué columna se relaciona con la tabla `saida_produto` y qué columnas quieres mostrar de esa otra tabla.

Comment: solo necesito el nombre del producto es esta la field ( est_producto )

Comment: A ver, cuando preguntas debes dar los detalles de lo que quieres: _Necesito mostrar las columnas `...` de las tabla `productos` y las columnas `...` de la tabla `estoque`. La tabla `productos` tiene la siguiente estructura: `campos de tabla productos`  y la columna `estoque` tiene la siguiente estructura: `campos de la tabla estoque`. Ambas tablas  se relacionan mediante los campos `campos por los que se relacionan`. He intentado esto y obtengo esto._ Si hubieses redactado la pregunta así ya tendrías respuesta. En caso contrario, tenemos que adivinarlo casi todo o someterte a interrogatorio.

Comment: lo hize de esta manera    SELECT saida_produto.saiprod_codproduto, estoque.est_produto,saida_produto.saiprod_quantidade,saida_produto.saiprod_valorproduto,
saida_produto.saiprod_valortotal
from saida_produto
INNER JOIN estoque on saida_produto.saiprod_codproduto=estoque.est_produto
where saida_produto.saiprod_cod_saida_pai = 1
group by
saiprod_codproduto,saiprod_quantidade,est_produto,saiprod_valorproduto,saiprod_valortotal                                                                                                      sale este error al ejecutar        conversion error from string

Answer (score 0):

Debería de funcionar, aquí te dejo el código mas limpio

`SELECT s.saiprod_codproduto, 
        e.est_produto,
        s.saiprod_quantidade,
        s.saiprod_valorproduto, 
        s.saiprod_valortotal
FROM saida_produto s
INNER JOIN estoque e
    ON s.saiprod_codproduto=e.est_produto 
WHERE s.saiprod_cod_saida_pai = 1 
GROUP BY 1,3,2,4,5`

Anexa el mensaje de error si sale...